# Как создаётся файл .AVI и/или .MJPG из jpeg-кадров на С++?

Tags: c++, видео, jpeg

В программе на C++ идёт непрерывный поток кадров в формате jpeg (снимает вебкамера). Кадры на диск не попадают, всё в буфере. Нужно по мере поступления кадра, или группы кадров, дописывать их в один файл на диске - **видеоконтейнер с покадровым сжатием**.

Поскольку с видео на таком низком уровне я дела не имел, а файл надо формировать вручную, прошу помочь с тем, какие заголовки в каком контейнере используются (интересуют mjpeg и avi).
Я так понимаю, что общая схема такова:
*заголовок_файла -> заголовок_кадра -> буфер_кадра -> заголовок_кадра ->...*
Если это так, то какая информация должна быть указана в этих заголовках?

Comment: Используйте libav. Или даже ffmpeg, если он осилит сам получать данные с камеры.

Comment: @VTT, просто хотелось бы также понимать в деталях как устроены видео контейнеры. Да и мне нужна статическая линковка, а если линковать с ffmpeg, экзешник в 10 мб раздуется до 85, что неразумно для одной задачи

Comment: Ничего он не раздуется, в libav можно достаточно гибко настроить включаемые компоненты.